# Finding rank-nullity of a given matices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be a $4 \times 7$ real matrix and $B$ be a $7 \times 4$ real matrix such that $AB=I_4$. Which of the following are true?
>
> 1) rank$(A)=4$
>
> 2) rank$(B)=7$
>
> 3) nullity$(B)=0$
>
> 4) $BA=I_7$.

My attempt:

$4=\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)}\}$. So $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ must be $4$. It shows that 1) is true

2) is false by Dimension theorem

How to check 3) and 4) ?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem? Think about the rank of $B$, using the same reasoning you used to answer the first question. This will help you with the third and fourth.

Comment: By the same reasoning you used to prove 1), you can see that 4) is always false (either from 1 or from the falsity of 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check (3):

If $nullity(B) \neq \{0\}$ there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $Bx = 0$. Premultiplying this last equality by $A$ you get $0 = ABx = Ix = x$, a contradiction.

Check (4):

Take

$$
A = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B = A^T
$$

Comment: Very clear! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct for the first two. For the third one, your reasoning for the first part also shows that $B$ has rank no smaller than $4$ (and since $B$ has rank no more than $4$, $B$ had rank $4$). Consequently, by the rank-nullity theorem (which tells us that $\mathrm{rank}\, B+\mathrm{null}\, B = 4$), the nullity of $B$ is $0$. For the fourth question, this is impossible, since the rank of $B$ is less than $7$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks....I got it